# RPi 3b+; updating bluez to 5.50-1.2~deb10u2 fails/hangs/

Tags: raspbian, bluetooth, apt, troubleshooting, bluez

As topic says, after running `apt update` the OS (running `Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)` on `kernel 5.10.52-v7+`) wants me to update `bluez` and its dependencies. The version it's trying to update to is `5.50-1.2~deb10u2` - however, this process hangs every time when it reaches the stage `"Setting up bluez (5.50-1.2~deb10u2)"` and the only way to get anywhere is to press `ctrl+c`/`ctrl+z` and exit mid-update (unless this is supposed to take 60min++ and I've not shown enough patience yet....). And of course, after canceling mid-update it takes some time to clean up the mess left behind, which is annoying.

Anyone else experienced this with this specific update, or any suggestions to what I can check to why this happens? I have disabled the onboard bluetooth in the `/boot/config.txt` and use an `ASUS USB-BT500` adapter instead, but I'd be surprised if having it configured this way should be the cause of this issue.

I can of course just put the update on `hold` with `apt-mark` but I'd prefer if there was a way to get it installed and have a more up-to-date bluez version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of trying, failing and frustration, I ended up running `sudo dpkg --force-depends -r bluez`, which surprisingly finished without freezing, and after that I could install the newest update the usual way `sudo apt install bluez`, so all is good now.